# Code is executed in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, function

I know that Javascript is asynchronous, but in this case I can't see why what's happens happen.

On line 27 below I call the function 'GetProducer' which is supposed to return data for a specific producer that I aim to use later on. However, when consoling it out it gets undefined, which is because the code on line 28 is executed before the data is retrieved (line 27).

How come this happens and what can I do to solve it?

```
1.     function GetProducer(id) {
2.  
3.          $.ajaxSetup ({
4.            url: "http://localhost/api/v1/producers/" + id,
5.            type: "GET",
6.            dataType: "json",
7.            cache: false,
8.            contentType: "application/json"
9.          })
10.         $.ajax({
11.             success: function(data){
12.                 return data;
13.             },
14.             error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
15.                 console.log(xmlHttpRequest);
16.                 console.log(textStatus);
17.                 console.log(errorThrown);
18.            }
19.         }).done(function(data){
20.             console.log(data);
21.         })
22.      }
23.
24.     $('.modal-btn').click(function(){
25.         var producerId = $(this).attr('id');
26.         $('#myModalLabel').html(producerId);
27.         var info = GetProducer(producerId);
28.         console.log(info); // <--- undefined
29.     });
```

Comment: Thanks for line-numbers.

Comment: As you said, it's asynch. `GetProducer` finishes its work at an arbitrary time in the future, almost certainly after the `console.log()`.

Comment: Javascript is synchronous, Ajax calls can be asynchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `return` statement inside an ajax callback function is useless. The function is invoked asynchronously and you can't expect anything to pass along your returned values to anything.

If you put your `console.log()` call **inside** the "success" callback, you'll see a value.

You'll probably need to change your "GetProducer" function such that it too takes a callback argument:

```
    GetProducer(producerId, function(info) { ... });
```

The function would then look like this, more or less:

```
  function GetProducer(producerId, callback) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      // ... same
    });
    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
      },
      // etc
    });
  }
```

The callback function, therefore, would be where you place the code that deals with the "producer" information.  Asynchronous programming is all about giving the API functions that handle the results *when the results become available.*

Comment: +1. Slightly different option is to return $.Deferred from `GetProducer` and call `GetProducer(producerId).then(function(result){...})`, in success callback resolve the deferred and pass the data instead of `return data;` do something like `deferred.resolve(data);`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes definitely.  I'm thinking the OP may wish to walk before he runs, but then perhaps to the uninitiated the Deferred feature is easier to understand!

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any suggestions what I should do with the callback argument you're suggesting me to put in? I'm not quite with you I'm afraid...

Comment: @holyredbeard I'll add stuff to the answer

Comment: An even easier solution is just to `return $.ajax({...})` and use the promise interface of the ajax object directly or possibly do `$.ajax({...}).pipe(successfilter,failfilter,etc)` in case you want to transform and/or don't want to return the ajax's deferred (no need to create deferreds directly, `pipe` does that for you).